# Adding .3g2 files

Tags: zune, video, lumia, file-format

I would like to transfer some .3g2 videos from my old phone to my Lumia 800. It seems that the [Lumia 800 supports that particular file format](http://www.pocket-lint.com/review/5616/nokia-lumia-800-wp7-review), but Zune does not. I can't even see the files through Zune. How can I put the files from my computer onto my Lumia 800?

Comment: Have you tried changing the file extension to .mp4 or something?  Does it transfer and play after doing that?

Comment: I can't see the files in Zune even after changing the extension.

Comment: I tried to transfer a .3gp file from pc to my lumia 710 but it couldn't transfer.. But the same file I tried to download from internet I was able to watch but didn't save as usual... But just after 2nd day I tried the same but it is not showing video from any website and poping msg we could not this this video in your phone but its showing videos from youtube..
It also happened with youtube then I increases the 'reserve memory' with the help of zune... But still its not showing videos from other sites rather than youtube...

Answer (score 2):

One option you could use, would be to upload them to OneDrive (or a similar service) - there is a native [OneDrive app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/onedrive/9wzdncrfj1p3), and that should be able to launch the video when it is in a supported format.

Comment: I can see the file but I can't download it. I'm starting to suspect my phone doesn't support this file format.

Answer (score 2):

The container is one thing and the codec another. Here you can see the official list of file formats and codecs supported.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087(VS.92).aspx